# How can I use adMob on a hosted cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob, ads

Is there a way to integrate `adMob` onto a hosted web app that's wrapped in `cordova`? I know its simple with a regular `cordova` app. But what about when my `cordova` app just redirects to a website? Is there any way to get this to work? I'd like to be able to load an ad any time the user dies or restarts the game.

Answer (score 0):

Admob provides ads to mobiles not web sites.Since your Cordova app is running on a browser use Adsense instead. https://www.google.com/adsense